# If ethyl bromide is treated with alcoholic silver nitrate, which product will be formed?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Silver nitrate promotes ionisation , so the ethyl bromide should ionise, the alcoholic species should attack (by loan pair of oxygen) so finally an ether should be formed , but the answer given in my book is nitroethane and ethyl nitrite.

Comment: Do you mean ethyl nitrile ($\ce{CH3CH2CN}$) or ethyl nitrite ($\ce{CH3CH2ONO}$)? I find it hard to see how ethyl nitrile could be formed at all.

Comment: The book probably assumes that the 'alcohol' is not a very nucleophilic one, so the nitrate ion attacks; and as the nitrate ion is bidentate... Everything adds up, except for the alcohol not participating at all; I'd also have thought it would do something, but there you go.

Comment: @user6376297 how nitrate can add to form nitroethane, this is my confusion, I can see formation of nitroethane when nitrite is used, but when nitrate is used , how nitroethane form ?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88515/reaction-of-tert-butyl-bromide-with-silver-nitrate

Comment: @Mithoron, the dupe question is alkyl halide + silver "nitrite" but this question specifically asks about silver "nitrate".

Comment: @NilayGhosh It's OP's typo, pretty obvious from context.