# Preparation of p-chlorobenzoic acid from p-chloronitrobenzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

I was reading my book where I spotted the preparation of *p*-chlorobenzoic acid from *p*-chloronitrobenzene.

The preparation method there was given as such:

1. $\ce{Sn/HCl}$
2. $\ce{NaNO2 + HCl}$ ($\pu{0-5 ^\circ C}$)
3. $\ce{CuCN}$
4. $\ce{H2O/H+}$

Now, the thing is that, I recall the first two steps from the process of forming diazonium salts but I have never seen the last two steps give the $\ce{-COOH}$ group.

Also I recall that $\ce{CuCN}$ gives us the nucleophile $\ce{CN-}$ where the negative charge is on the nitrogen atom and also that $\ce{H2O/H+}$ is used for hydration but I don't see how these two could help us form *p*-chloronitrobenzene from Benzenediazonium chloride.

Comment: The reaction of CuCN with the diazonium salt is a Sandmeyer reaction. The last step is a hydrolysis of the nitrile formed in the Sandmeyer reaction.

Comment: You recall incorrectly, the negative charge in cyanide is on the carbon

Comment: @user55119 But isn't the sandmeyer reaction only for halogens ,for eg NaCl and NaBr?

Comment: Read this  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandmeyer_reaction

Comment: @Waylander But isn't it of the format of AgCN where the - charge is on the N atom?

Comment: No, in general cyanide is nucleophilic through carbon  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanide

Comment: @Waylander But we do have Ambident nucleophiles, for eg in NaCN and KCN charge in cyanide is on carbon whereas in AgCN , charge is on nitrogen.

Comment: Yes, we do. This answer explains why  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58104/why-do-sn2-reactions-of-alkyl-halides-proceed-differently-with-kcn-and-agcn  but in general when you see cyanide ion - unless it is AgCN - assume that the nucleophilic reaction is through carbon.

Comment: CN- and NC- are different. One is called cyanide ion, other one is called isocyanide ion. Also, correct the spelling of nucleophile in your question.

Comment: @TheChemist Please don't delete `\pu{…}` macro in posts. See [Undefined control sequence \pu in official SE Android app](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3834/undefined-control-sequence-pu-in-official-se-android-app). The problem doesn't lie with the macro, it's the mobile app that you are likely using that hasn't been updated for a long time.

Comment: Oh ok didn't know that. Thanks for telling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply the summery of all comments involved:

$$\ce{Cl-C6H4-NO2 ->[Sn/HCl] Cl-C6H4-NH3+Cl-} \tag1$$

$$\ce{Cl-C6H4-NH3+Cl- ->[\text{a. } NaNO2/HCl \ (\pu{0-5 ^\circ C})][\text{b. } CuCN] Cl-C6H4-CN} \\ \tag2$$

$$\ce{Cl-C6H4-CN ->[H+/H2O][\Delta] Cl-C6H4-COOH} \\ \tag3$$

Note: The reaction $(1)$ is a typical reduction reaction, which reduce nitro group to amino group. The reaction $(2)$ is called [Sandmeyer Reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandmeyer_reaction). Finally, The reaction $(3)$ is a hydrolysis condition to convert cyano group to carboxylic acid group. That hydrolysis can be done under basic conditions as well (then, final product is carboxalate).

---

*Also note that even though it is not necessary, I put this answer up just to avoid people asking same kind of questions again and again. When they have a visual answer they might not do so.*